# Create Org Shape: Error (1): The requested resource does not exist

Tags: salesforcedx, org-shape

My Dev Hub org and the source org are the same. I've followed all the instructions to setup Org Shape from the [docs](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_dev.meta/sfdx_dev/sfdx_dev_shape_intro.htm). Once I get to the point to create the shape, I get this error:

```
sf org create shape --target-org prod 

Error (1): The requested resource does not exist
```

These are the object permissions assigned to my user
[image]

How do I troubleshoot this?